# How to sort a list by a certain order in Common Lisp?

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp

So i know how to sort a list like `(1 2 3)` 
by ascended order for example in Common Lisp.

But i need to sort this list: `( (1 2 3) nil 1)` in descending order of the **3rd** element.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "descending order of the 3rd element"? And I think your list (the second one) has one extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: I mean order it like this; '( (1 2 3) nil 1) '( (1 2 3) nil 2) , and so on

Comment: I suppose you mean Common Lisp. If so, then the `sort` function has a second argument, the predicate, which is exactly the function that compares elements. See here: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm

Comment: 1...2... is ascending, not descending.

Comment: but in those examples i think they only use a  simple list with no sub-lists in it ?

Comment: Yes - but you could write a function and pass it as the predicate. (I'm still not sure if this is what you want)

Comment: What is the third element of `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sort` function accepts a predicate that will be used to tell when an element precedes another (see the [hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm)).

So, define a function `compare-3rd`:

```
(defun compare-3rd (a b)
  (< (nth 2 a) (nth 2 b)))
```

And use it as the predicate:

```
(sort '(( (1 2 3) nil 4)
    ( (1 2 3) nil 2)
    ( (1 2 3) nil 3))
      'compare-3rd)

==> (((1 2 3) NIL 2) ((1 2 3) NIL 3) ((1 2 3) NIL 4))
```

Of course, if you want descending order you may use `>` instead of `<` in `compare-3rd`.

Comment: Oh, i didnt understand that i could use a function of mine in sort ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Instead of the custom comparison, you can give it as the `:key` keyword argument: `(sort list #'< :key #'third)`.